# clearcase syncreplica import error

Tags: import, clearcase

I am trying to import 25 packets from the incoming bay on my vob server.
An `lspacket` of each of the packet shows that the packets are fragments from 1 to 25.
Here's an example:

```
multitool lspacket sync_XXX_12977
Packet is: /clearcase/shipping/ms_ship/incoming/sync_XXX_12977
Packet type: Update
Packet fragment: 1 of 25

...

multitool lspacket sync_XXX_12977_6
Packet is: /clearcase/shipping/ms_ship/incoming/sync_XXX_12977_6
Packet type: Update
Packet fragment: 6 of 25

...and so on upto _25.
```

So to import all the fragments/packets at once, I did a `syncreplica -import` [all packets from `sync_XXX_12977` to `sync_XXX_12977_25`].
With this I get an error like:

```
multitool: Error: Unable to write file "/var/tmp/syncs04042": No space left on device.
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Also, I should mention that incoming packets for other vobs seem to have lesser number of fragments, and they are successfully imported by the scheduled `sync_receive`.
I'm not sure why this error is coming only for packets for this particular vob. Could it be because of larger number of fragments?

---

Here is some more info about the error:

```
multitool: Error: Vob server operation "Create Container" failed.
           Additional information may be available in the vob_log on host "VOBserver.qwerty.com"
multitool: Error: Unable to create a container in vob "/vobs/products", because group "root" not in vob's group list.
multitool: Error: Unable to replay oplog entry 927736: Not owner.
927736:
op= checkin
replica_oid= 9c863907.23ca11e2.9baf.00:01:83:db:e4:2d (ABC_SW)
oplog_id= 659061
op_time= 2014-06-06T07:18:47Z  create_time= 2014-07-31T09:18:01Z
version_oid= 8426e33c.ed4b11e3.931b.00:01:83:db:e4:2d (*no view*)
event comment= "created by clearfsimport"
data size= 116  data= 0x12e108
------------
ver_oid= 8426e33c.ed4b11e3.931b.00:01:83:db:e4:2d (*no view*)
ver_num= 1
ver_fstat= ino: 0; type: 1; mode: 00
           usid: DONTCARE
           gsid: DONTCARE
           nlink: 0; size: 130017856
           atime: Thu Jan  1 05:30:00 1970
           mtime: Fri Jun  6 12:48:14 2014
           ctime: Fri Jun  6 12:48:14 2014
ckout_ver_oid= 8426e33c.ed4b11e3.931b.00:01:83:db:e4:2d (*no view*)
```

I checked vob's properties using lsvob -long and desc: the vob owner and group are CC admin and ccgrp.

Answer (score 1):

If those packets are particularly big, that might explain the  "`No space left on device`" message.

The first check is to do a:

```
cd /var/tmp
df -h .
```

And check what space you have left to work.

---

Once that disk space issue is fixed, you should:

- get the primary group of the vob (`cleartool descr -l vob:/vobs/products`)
- check that `id -a` (for `ccadmin`) returns that group as primary group (meaning the first group displayed by that command should be the one of the vob)

Comment: Thanks VonC. I logged-in as root and cleaned-up some unwanted files under the root partition (which was 99% full). I ran the import command again and this time it gave me the following error: "multitool: Error: Vob server operation "Create Container" failed.". As far as I know, there are no permission issues with the vob, but I will double check. Also, there is a sync_receive running right now. Is it possible that sync_receive and my manual import conflicted?

Comment: Also, the packets in question are only 5Mb each.

Comment: @AashishSharma it is possible the two `sync_receive` could be a source of conflict, if they are accessing the same resources.